# Sort a custom post with ACF: Date Picker & Display Featured!

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, sort, date-time

Hello I have a custom post type `event` and i have two custom fields:

1. event_date
2. event_type

I want to display all my events which has `event_type` = `Featured` and sorting should be by `event_date` in `DESC` order..

I have searched everywhere on SOF but unable to find any working solution.. Here is my code right now

```
$events = new WP_Query(
                            array(
                                'post_type' => 'event',
                                'post_status' => 'publish',
                                'meta_key' => 'event_type',
                                'meta_value' => 'featured',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'orderby' => 'event_date',
                                'order' => 'DESC'
                            )
                        );
```

screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change your args like this.

```
$meta_query = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_type',
        'value' => 'featured',
        'compare' => '='
    )
);

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'event_date',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query
);
```